# What does Salikoko Mufwene mean with regards to #3 on the progressive aspect?

Tags: semantics, aspect

[From Wikipedia:](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Continuous_and_progressive_aspects)

> Salikoko Mufwene contrasts the effect of the progressive form on the
> meanings of action verbs versus those of lexically stative verbs:
>
> 1. It converts events expected to be punctual into longer-lasting, even if transient, states of affairs [e.g., "Nancy is writing a
>    letter"];
> 2. It [con]versely converts those states of affairs expected to last long (lexical statives) to shorter-lasting / transient states of
>    affairs [e.g., "Tom is living with us"]; and
> 3. It simply presents those verbs whose denotations are neutral with regard to duration as in process / in (transient) duration [e.g., "The
>    wall is cracking"], though duration is most expected of statives.

Points #1 and #2 are self-explanatory, but Point #3 is unclear. What is Dr. Mufwene saying in Point #3?

Comment: It seems fairly self-explanatory to me – can you clarify what it is exactly that you find difficult to understand about it?

Comment: @JanusBahsJacquet "Neutral with regards to duration" doesn't make any logical sense.

Comment: Why not? Not all verbs denote actions that are inherently expected to be either punctual or long-lasting (stative). _Crack_ is a good example – it doesn’t specify a crack appearing all at once, but it doesn’t necessarily have to be a general state of affairs for a longer period of time. I think #1 is stranger, because _write_ is not punctual either – it’s a bad example. “Nancy is tearing up a letter” would be a better example.

Comment: @JanusBahsJacquet Where would Zeno Vendler classify "to write", "to tear up" and "to crack" in his classification schema? https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lexical_aspect

Comment: I would say that _write_ is an activity and _tear up [a letter]_ is an accomplishment. Not entirely sure whether to label _crack_ as achievement or activity, but in Moens and Steedman’s model given further down on that page, I’d classify it as semelfactive (culminating event only).